# How implement back pressure manually

Tags: node.js, stream, es6-promise, child-process, asynchronous-javascript

i have child process in that i am piping stream to parent.

in child.js

```
  let stream = readdirp(pathname);
  stream.pipe.pipe(process.stdout);
```

in parent.js

```
let file = child => {
  let estream = es.map((data, next) => {
    _this.s3MultiUpload(JSON.parse(data), data, next);
    //i uploding this files to s3.
  });
  child.on("end", (code, signal) => {
    console.log("stream ended"); // `here is my problem`
    child.kill();
  });
  child.on("exit", (code, signal) => {
    console.log(code);
    console.log(signal);
    child.kill();
  });
  return estream;
};
child = fork(filePath, { silent: true });
child.stdout.pipe(this.file(child));
```

My problem is before i upload all files to s3 stream got ended. i studied about backpressure, but i don't understand how to implement here ?

i think i need add callback or something to process stdout pipe. i don't know

Can you please help me

Comment: You are making things way more complicated than you need to by forking. IO isn't CPU bound so you would be better off with `Promise.all(await  util.promisify(fs.readDir)(pathname)).map(file => ...)`. Also, just for the sake of argument https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/774635475071934464

Comment: @AluanHaddad i can't understand, can you please elaborate ??

Comment: I'm saying you don't need to use child processes, ad-hoc observable like mechanisms, or even callbacks. Just use the JavaScript language along with the NodeJS builtin modules `util` and `fs`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad At first i tried in main process only, if have huge files inside the directory means my thread hangs, so moved that to another thread. and i am using readdirp for reading in nested directory, and add filters,and for more options

Comment: Are you processing the file or just uploading it? Promises prevent blocking even with a single thread ***when*** your workload is IO bound as opposed to CPU bound

Comment: @AluanHaddad, just uploading

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes i will try , Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is unecessarily complicated. Since, IO operations aren't CPU bound we are better off using Promises together with JavaScript's `async`/`await` and `*` syntax to perform the parallel file uploading. Building our own synchronization mechanisms is complex and there are many overlapping language and library level concepts that arise<sup>**1**</sup>.

Based on the [*readdirp* documentation](https://github.com/paulmillr/readdirp#readdirp-), but noting my unfamiliarity with the specific upload API, I'd suggest something along these lines

```
const readdirp = require('readdirp');
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const readfile = util.promisify(fs.readfile);

(async function () {
  // Use streams to achieve small RAM & CPU footprint.
  // 1) Streams example with for-await. Node.js 10+ only.
  const paths = [];
  for await (const {path} of readdirp('pending-uploads')) {
    paths.push(path);
  }

  const uploadPromises = paths
    .map(readFile)
    .map(JSON.parse).
    .map(data => s3MultiUpload(data));

  await Promise.all(uploadPromises);
}());
```

**<sup>1</sup>**.Back pressure is one of these concepts arising from the process of porting the Reactive Extensions library to the JVM implementing it in Java. Just for the sake of argument(sanity?) consider [what Erik Meijer says regarding backpressure](http://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/774635475071934464).